# Invalid UINavigationBar appearance when open iMessage within an app

Tags: ios, uikit

After setting

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = COLOR_TINT;
```

i got this appearance launching iMessage within an app

[image]

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: textfield has an invalid background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you set the bar tint in the app delegate?

try setting the tint in every controller instead...

Comment: Yes that makes sense (**not**). It's best practice to set the bar tint color through the appearance proxy in a category on UINavigationBar. Setting it manually in every controller is an dumb way of styling the navigation bar throughout your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = nil;
```

should set before initialization.  Like this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = nil;
MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't want your MFMessageComposeViewController don't have the same appearance.

Before present your Message ViewController, set barTintColor to default Color which is nil.

`UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = nil ;`

and recover your barTintColor after MFMessageComposeViewController is dismissed.

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] ;
    UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = COLOR_TINT ;
}
```